# What is this data structure with default property and type-like object in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, data-structures

I notice that in some JS objects, they have properties with some special behaviours. For example, the model objects in Sequelize, if I log a model to the console, I see that the object contains properties such as `_data`, `_changed`, `_modelOptions`, etc.

However, when accessing the object itself, the `_data` property appears to be its default property. For instance:

```
const userModel = UserModel.findOne(...);
console.log(userModel.email);   // this prints the email field of the record
console.log(userModel._data.dataValues.email)  // this also prints the email of the record
```

It appears that I don't have to access the `email` from `_data.dataValues`. I can access it directly from the `userModel` object.

When I print the whole object, I also notice that the values in `_data.dataValues` get printed.

With this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(userModel))
```

I will get this result:

```
{
   name: 'John',
   email: 'john@smith.com'
}
```

But with this:

```
console.log(userModel)
```

I will get this instead:

```
t {
   _data: user {   // what is that 'user'  before the object? is it a type definition?
      dataValues: {
         name: 'John',
         email: 'john@smith.com'
      }
      _previousDataValues: {
         name: 'John',
         email: 'john@smith.com'
      }
      _modelOptions: {
         ...
      }
      ...
   }
}
```

This looks a little different from the usual JS object in that it seems to have a "type" of sort to the object those properties are "internal" and not visible when printed out.

I thought it was a class at first but I tried printing a class I've created and compared the output with the console output from this model and they look different.

I don't see this data structure in JS often. What is this data structure in JS and in Node specifically? What is different and useful about this "special" object compared to the regular object in JS?

Comment: Might be an indication of the class that the object is an instance of - eg, there's a `class user` that was called, with the result assigned to the `_data` property, is my guess

Comment: `JSON.stringify(user)` will print the result of `user.toJSON()`, which can return whatever it wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achieving these form of behaviour is nothing special. This can be done easily using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) or [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties).

Here is an example

```js
function Person(fName, lName) {
  this._data = {
    fName: fName,
    lName: lName
  }
  
  Object.defineProperties(this, {
    fName: {
      get : function () {
        return this._data.fName;
      },
      set: function (value) {
        this._data.fName = value;
      }
    },
    lName: {
      get : function () {
        return this._data.lName;
      },
      set: function (value) {
        this._data.lName = value;
      }
    }
  });  
}

const ratul = new Person("Ratul", "sharker");

console.log(ratul);

console.log(ratul.fName);
ratul.fName = "Ra2l";
console.log(ratul.fName);
```

Here the `enumerable` property is by default set to `false` (check define properties documentation.) If you set it to `true` then it will appear in `console.log(ratul)`.

Primary usage of these sort of behaviour in sequelize is to keep track of value changes. Directly from [Sequelize github](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/fbd19d986170ad1edeeba123a0730854824aa515/lib/model.js#L3481).

```
setDataValue(key, value) {
    const originalValue = this._previousDataValues[key];

    if (!_.isEqual(value, originalValue)) {
      this.changed(key, true);
    }

    this.dataValues[key] = value;
  }
```

Most obvious reason to track data value changes is to while calling `Model.save`, then sequelize can optimise which attributes/properties should sequelize write to db.

[This is where](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/fbd19d986170ad1edeeba123a0730854824aa515/lib/model.js#L1237) `Object.defineProperty` is being used, which is declared within `refreshAttributes`, which is called from `init`.

```
Object.defineProperty(this.prototype, key, attributeManipulation[key]);
```