# How to get access to object return by sequelize find function

Tags: javascript, find, sequelize.js

I am new to sequelize and I am trying to figure out how to store the returned value from the select statement. My code is:

```
try {
      var teamStats = await models.stats.findAll({
        where: { weekId: season + '-' + previousWeek }
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
```

but if I console.log(teamStats), I get :

```
stats {
  dataValues: {
    id: 2,
    wins: 0,
    losses: 1,
    ties: 0,
    power_rank: 0,
    plays_for: 67,
    yards_for: 345,
    yards_per_play_for: 5.2,
    plays_against: 49,
    yards_against: 269,
    yards_per_play_against: 5.5,
    net_yards_per_play: -0.3,
    spread_value: -1.5,
    createdAt: 2020-03-02T03:34:43.000Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-03-02T03:34:43.000Z,
    teamId: 68,
    weekId: '2019-regular-1'
  },
  _previousDataValues: {
    id: 2,
    wins: 0,
    losses: 1,
    ties: 0,
    power_rank: 0,
    plays_for: 67,
    yards_for: 345,
    yards_per_play_for: 5.2,
    plays_against: 49,
    yards_against: 269,
    yards_per_play_against: 5.5,
    net_yards_per_play: -0.3,
    spread_value: -1.5,
    createdAt: 2020-03-02T03:34:43.000Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-03-02T03:34:43.000Z,
    teamId: 68,
    weekId: '2019-regular-1'
  },
  _changed: {},
  _modelOptions: {
 ...
```

I tried to access it by teamStats.stats.dataValues but It was coming back undefined.

Comment: Solved this by just doing teamStats.toJSON()

Answer (score 0):

Access model properties as follows

```
teamStats.forEach(stat => {
    console.log(stat.win);
});
```

‘findAll’ returns an array so the return promise will resolve to an array of models.

To access first you need to iterate over the result array, then accessing it’s property directly.

Do not try to access properties by looking at the console log of the returned models. It might fool you a bit. Check this question, why this might cause so much confusion.

[What is this data structure with default property and type-like object in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59798769/what-is-this-data-structure-with-default-property-and-type-like-object-in-js/59799925#59799925)